# External vs Internal JS - MBean value

Tags: javascript, xhtml, jmx

I'm having trouble getting values from MBean when my javascript is in an external file.

Example:

```html
<script src='scripts/externaljs.js' type='text/javascript' />
<script>
   getString();
<script>
```

```js
//externaljs.js

function getString(){
   var string = "#{testMBean.getName()}";
   alert(string);
}
```

It always returns "#{testMBean.getName()}" instead of the string value.
But if I declare it inside my .xhtml file it returns the proper value.

```js
<script>
   var string = "#{testMBean.getName()}";
   alert(string);
</script>
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your MBean value is only substituted in your view. If you want your external JavaScript file to see those values you can store them in an array / object, or pass them as arguments.

```
<script>
  var mBeanValues = {
    string: "#{testMBean.getName()}"
  }
</script>

<script src="external.js></script>

<script>
  getString()
</script>

=====

// external.js
function getString() {
  alert(mBeanValues.string)
}
```

OR

```
<script src="external.js"></script>

<script>
  getString("#{testMBean.getName()}")
</script>

=====

// external.js
function getString(string) {
  alert(string)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine using the MBean values as arguments.